# Deserializing an unknown type in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I just got a hold of `JSON.NET` and its been great so far.

However, I cannot figure out how to determine the `type` of a serialized object when deserializing it.

How can I determine the object's class to cast it?

To clarify my question, let's say I wanted to do this

```
string json = <<some json i don't know>>
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
if (data is Person)
{
   //do something
}
else if (data is Order)
{
   //do something else
}
```

Does Json.NET support this kind of functionality?

Comment: That was my first thought too. However, the type is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Comment: JSON is a plain format and not keep metadata on serialization. You MUST know what type you are deserialize.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, how can I differentiate between different objects then? When a client sends something to my server, I have to be able to detect what it is

Comment: How client sends data to your server? You must have some protocol to determine what client sent.

Comment: If GetType() returns JObject the the value of the key simply another json object. You need to recurse into it and read the subsequent keys.

Answer (score 33):

you can use `dynamic` type

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSONtext)
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(serializedMessage).GetType());` just gives me `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Comment: i think Json can't recognize the type of object. you need to check it manually.

Answer (score 13):

it may help you

```
IDictionary < string, JToken > Jsondata = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString);
   foreach(KeyValuePair < string, JToken > element in Jsondata)
    {
           string innerKey = element.Key;
            if (element.Value is JArray)
             {
                  // Process JArray
             }
            else if (element.Value is JObject) 
            { 
                  // Process JObject
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you control the serialization, you can use the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) setting

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
var toBeSerialized = settings; // use the settings as an example data to be serialized

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toBeSerialized, Formatting.Indented, settings);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, settings);

var deserializedType = deserialized.GetType().Name; // JsonSerializerSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still trying to do this, I suggest to use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(JSONtext)
```

Comment: WTH is ExpandoObject??

Comment: @AdamHey why would one ask smth on SO before googling