# Deserializing JSON to .NET

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

How to deserialize json of this kind into an object on C# ?

```
{
   "AND":[
      {
         "AND":[
            {
               "AND":[
                  {
                     "AND":[
                        {
                           "AND":[
                              {
                                 "AND":[
                                    {
                                       "OR":[
                                          {
                                             "OR":[
                                                "Title",
                                                "Login"
                                             ]
                                          },
                                          "LoginNote"
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    "BossTitle"
                                 ]
                              },
                              {
                                 "OR":[
                                    "Phone",
                                    "TeleGorod"
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        "Room"
                     ]
                  },
                  "Division"
               ]
            },
            "TabelnyiNomer"
         ]
      },
      "Filter\""
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is .NET a format? what do you need, and what have you tried?

Comment: try https://quicktype.io/?l=cs&r=json2csharp

Comment: I think you need to use some of already existing .NET libraries like `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: @Backs 
...             ((OtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOtherOtherAND)value).WriteJson(writer, serializer);....
the tree can be arbitrary

Comment: @JosephKatzman
I watched this library
they do not say how to make an object from an arbitrary tree.

Comment: @AntonBobenko Do you know the structure of the object which you want to deserialize? Do you always get the same structure?

Comment: @AntonBobenko JSON is a plain format and not keep metadata on serialization. You must know what type you are deserialize.

Comment: @JosephKatzman 
1.No
2.No
Example
{"AND": ["_ x041f__x0435__x0440__x0432__x04"], {"AND": ["_ x0418__x0437__x0433__x043e__x04", {"AND": ["_ x041e__x043f__x0438__x0441__x04", {"AND": ["_ x041a__x043e__x0434_", "Title"]}]}]}] }

This is the logic for building a CAML request
consists of AND or OR, has two meanings and can be nested

Comment: @AntonBobenko Ok, I understood you. It might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246609/deserializing-an-unknown-type-in-json-net You can play with `dynamic` type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing an unknown type in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246609/deserializing-an-unknown-type-in-json-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with `dynamic` type, but I don't think it can help you.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string unknownJson1 = "{\r\n  \"Id\": \"1e4495d3-4cd1-4bf2-9da6-4acee2f7a70e\",\r\n  \"Customers\": [\r\n    \"Alice\",\r\n    \"Bob\",\r\n    \"Eva\"\r\n  ]\r\n}";
            string unknownJson2 = "{\"AND\": [\"_ x041f__x0435__x0440__x0432__x04\", {\"AND\": [\"_ x0418__x0437__x0433__x043e__x04\", {\"AND\": [\"_ x041e__x043f__x0438__x0441__x04\", {\"AND\": [\"_ x041a__x043e__x0434_\", \"Title\"]}]}]}] } ";

            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            dynamic deserializedObject;

            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(unknownJson2))
            {
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
                {
                    deserializedObject = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
This does not work for 


string unknownJson = "{\"AND\": [\"_ x041f__x0435__x0440__x0432__x04\", {\"AND\": [\"_ x0418__x0437__x0433__x043e__x04\", {\"AND\": [\"_ x041e__x043f__x0438__x0441__x04\", {\"AND\": [\"_ x041a__x043e__x0434_\", \"Title\"]}]}]}] } ";

Comment: @AntonBobenko It works. Look at the answer. I have just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

[quicktype's](https://quicktype.io) CLI supports JSON schema as an import format, which could help you represent the tree data structure you're parsing here. I'll look into why it wasn't detected automatically, but here's your model:

```cs
public class Tree
{
    [JsonProperty("AND")]
    public Leaf[] And { get; set; } // Could be null

    [JsonProperty("OR")]
    public Leaf[] Or { get; set; } // Could be null
}

public struct Leaf
{
    public string String; // Could be null
    public Top Tree; // Could be null
}
```

Your JSON should parse as this, although I haven't tested it.